# Are there any URL shortening services that support protocol relative urls?

Tags: url, web, url-shortener

I need to shorten a protocol relative url such as `//www.example.com/longurl` into another protocol relative url `//short/url` so an iframe can be embedded on a page independent of the used protocol. Are there any free URL shortening services that allow this? I've tried isgd, tinyurl, googl, bitly, owly among others, but they all either don't accept the url or prepend it with `http://` so it turns into `http:////www.example.com/longurl`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It's undocument, but it turns out that goo.gl supports this, you just have to modify the URL it gives you, although it seems the URLs I tried were longer than what they accept.

Comment: Either goo.gl doesn't support this any more or I am doing it wrong. Can you provide an example. Thanks.

Comment: If you shorten e.g. `http://www.google.com` you get `http://goo.gl/3gcw5F`, you can replace this with `//goo.gl/3gcw5F`.